# Combine two GeoJSON files

Tags: leaflet, geojson, linestring

Is there a clever way to combine two or more geoJSON files? I would like to combine the two geoJSON files here: https://gist.github.com/szeconku/3c0d3021178d8598f04dc5273864bd81